# Can you tell me about this coin? श्री महेन्द्र वीर विक्रम शाहदेव 2012. i.e in English Sri Mahendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev 2012

Tags: identification, currency, money, numismatics

[image]

This is a photo of both sides of the coin.

Comment: Written in Hindi. But some letters are not clear, if any clear image is available then share it.

Comment: @Explorer Indeed. It is some sort of Devnagri script (I am sure it is Indic but idk if it is hindi or some other Indian language, if it is Hindi, it can't be that old.) What about the emblem in middle? The trident? Was it associated with any Indian Kingdom?

Comment: The trident(Symbol of Lord Shiva), is associated with Hindus as Nepal is a Hindu country and they worship [Lord Shiva](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupatinath_Temple)

Comment: "This is a photo of both sides of the coin" - are both obverse and reverse really identical?

Answer (score 13):

This coin is from Nepal and belongs to King of Nepal [Sri Mahendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahendra_of_Nepal) and came in existence in Vikrami Samvat 2012 (Gregorian calendar-1955).

letters inscribed are:-

> श्री महेन्द्र वीर विक्रम शाहदेव 2012.

i.e in English Sri Mahendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev 2012

Coin Sri Mahendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev, Vikrami Samvat 2012 (Gregorian calendar-1955)

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity: it looks like that some coins (the same) were embossed, and other engraved?

Comment: I was just surprised that the exact same coin (as far as i can tell from the photos) is engraved or embossed. I would expect one or the other, for the same coin.

Comment: Maybe one side is engraved and the other is embossed. As the OP said, both sides have the same figure.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** For the precise answer, see [Explorer's](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/25769/explorer) answer [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/39015/15625).

---

Begin my imprecise answer which was correct about origin but incorrect about the exact coin.

This appears to be a coin from Nepal. Searching details of text and era.

You can see a similar [commemorative coin here](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces26050.html):

[image]

The letters inscribed one the commemorative one are:

श्री श्री 

श्री ५ ज्ञानेन्द्रवीर विक्रम शाहदेव

२०६०

Which means

> Shree Gyanendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev 2060

Comment: Good find but the coin OP has posted is of King of Nepal, Sri Mahendra Bir Bikram Shah Dev(1955 to 1972). Vikrami Samvat, 2012-2029.
 I have found the pic.